# Why does dict.__iter__() iterate over the Python dictionary key values only?

Tags: python, dictionary

can anyone explain to me the why the design choice was made, that when calling `__iter__` on a Python dictionary this should iterate over the key values only?

I might be biased by coming from C++, where - when iterating over a `std::map` - one gets `std::map::value_type &` [i.e. `std::pair &`] values.

I encountered this question when debugging strange program behavior, where I had a situtation similar to the following one:

```
def method(one=None, two=None, three=None):
    print('one: {one}, two: {two}, three: {three}'.format(one=one, two=two, three=three))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    blub = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}    
    method(*blub)
    exit(0)
```

with the following output

```
one: one, two: two, three: three
```

whereas I would have expected

```
one: 1, two: 2, three: 3
```

. My mistake was not to call `method(**blub)` obviously, but - again, I come from C++ - it took me some time to find this out.

Additionally I would have liked a warning, that passing a `dict` with one asterisk only may be undesired - but that's not how Python works, is it?

Might I have detected my error more easily using e.g. `method(**kwargs)`? I don't see how, but maybe someone can enlighten me here as well.

Thanks in advance

Johannes

Comment: Note, even if iterating over a dictionary did iterate over key-value pairs, `method(*blub)` would still not work the way you expdct it to. Try it with `method(*blub.items())`

Comment: "Additionally I would have liked a warning, that passing a dict with one asterisk only may be undesired - but that's not how Python works, is it?" Why would it warn you?

Comment: Actually in this case you could use keyword-only argument in the function to avoid that error, if it's desirable.

Comment: what you are looking for is `dict.items()` which will return exactly what you are expecting from c++, as for the reason for this, i have seen in some video that it was really controversial, and they just decided that returning only keys is what most people want.

Comment: if you don't like how this works, you can write your own dictionary class by subclassing `dict` class and have it work the way you want, additionally (and a lot more trickier) is that you can tamper with the `dict` class inside python to do what you want, but this is guaranteed to break any external dependency.

Comment: Python gives `d.keys()`, `d.values()`, and `d.items()` to allow you to explicitly choose what to iterate over. `for x in d` or similar uses are just shortcuts, and "someone" decided to make them shortcuts for `keys()`, not for `values()` or `items()` (a decision which btw seems pretty natural to me, but this of course depends on your previous experiences).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: @user202729 Keyword-only arguments look interesting. Thanks for that hint.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Would you maybe still know in what video you saw that controversery? That's exactly what I wanted to know with this question. And maybe just to clarify again: I don't want to oppose this decision or complain about undefined behavior [everything is documented well] - I just want to know what lead to this design decision.